# Regex to extract only contact info from an MBOX file into a csv

Tags: php, arrays, regex, csv

As the title suggests I am trying to parse a large MBOX file (16,000 emails in one file) and I am working on a small file for my test.

My php so far is:

```
$string = file_get_contents("test.mbox");

$matches = array(); //create array

$patt = '/name:\s([^\r]+)|email:\s([^\r]+)/';

preg_match_all($patt, $string, $matches); //find matching pattern

print_r($matches);

$fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w');

foreach ($matches as $fields) {

    fputcsv($fp, $fields);

}

fclose($fp);
```

But my output needs to be in an easy to import format.
Currently my regex returns:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => name: Andrew
        [1] => email: andrew@gmail.com
        [2] => name: Second Dude
        [3] => email: second@gmail.com.au
        [4] => name: Stuart Richards
        [5] => email: stuart@gmail.com
        [6] => name: Stuart Richards2
        [7] => email: stuart2@gmail.com
        [8] => name: Stuart Richards3
        [9] => email: stuart3@gmail.com )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => Andrew
        [1] =>
        [2] => Second Dude
        [3] =>
        [4] => Stuart Richards
        [5] =>
        [6] => Stuart Richards
        [7] =>
        [8] => Stuart Richards
        [9] => )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => 
        [1] => andrew@gmail.com
        [2] =>
        [3] => second@gmail.com.au
        [4] =>
        [5] => stuart@gmail.com
        [6] =>
        [7] => stuart2@gmail.com
        [8] =>
        [9] => stuart3@gmail.com ) )
```

This is the data I want but appearing in a stepped look in CSV (Like a crosstab query for each field.
The top row containing a string like "name: Andrew, email: andrew@gmail.com, etc
The second row in csv contains just the name: "Andrew,,Second Dude,,"etc where they match on every second column.
The third contains the emails only as such: ",andrew@gmail.com,,second@gmail.com,,

I have 16 thousand emails with Name: Email: and two other headers in them and want to make it easy to import into my database so I need a csv with each piece of data as such: 
name1,email1,phone1
name2,email2,phone2
name3,email3,phone3

Could anyone please help me? I have tried many many things including working with the file once it has output in the crosstab format but no luck.
I tried making it add a linebreak after each regex but no luck.

I only started with php the weekend just gone and have used this site A LOT! So I will appreciate it if you can even just point me in the right direction to learn the syntax for what I want to do. I have just reached the point where I am clicking on links to resources I have read ten times already so thought I would ask for a bit of help.
Cheers
Andrew

Sample of my test mbox file:

```
---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: 
Date: Sat, Jan 3, 2015 at 9:38 AM
Subject: campaign Campaign (.INFO)
To: 


Visitor's IP: 58.165.117.
name: Andrew Cowley
suburb: Victoria point
email: andrew@gmail.com
phone: 04035752
powerbill: $500
System_Required: 
Date:Sat-Jan-2015 10:38:00
Key:

from:  - landing page



---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: 
Date: Sat, Jan 3, 2015 at 9:38 AM
Subject: campaign Campaign (.INFO)
To:


Visitor's IP: 58.165.117.
name: Second Dude
suburb: Victoria point
email: second@gmail.com.au
phone: 04035752
powerbill: $500
System_Required: 3kW
Date:Sat-Jan-2015 10:38:00
Key:

from: Adwords  - landing page



---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: 
Date: Sat, Jan 3, 2015 at 9:38 AM
Subject: campaign Campaign (.INFO)
To: 


Visitor's IP: 58.165.117.
name: Stuart Richards
suburb: Victoria point
email: mottu@gmail.com
phone: 04035752
powerbill: $500
System_Required: 3kW
Date:Sat-Jan-2015 10:38:00
Key:

from: Adwords  - landing page
```

Comment: could you post a sample of your mbox file?

Comment: Hi Casimir, I have just added a sample of a file I am trying to regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea is to build a pattern that extracts the two informations (name and email) in one single match and to use the option `PREG_SET_ORDER` to put all informations of a match (whole match and capture groups) in the same result array item:

```
$pattern = '~
^name: \h* (?<name> [^\r\n]+ ) \R
.* \R                              # skip the suburb line
email: \h* (?<mail> [^\r\n]+ )
~mx';

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $mbox, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach($m as $item) {
        echo $item['name'] . ',' . $item['mail'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Glossary:

```
\R             # any kind of newlines 
\h             # an horizontal whitespace
(?<blah>...)   # a named capture
^              # is by default an anchor for the start of the string,
               # but when the m modifier is used, it becomes an anchor 
               # for the start of the line.
m modifier     # change the meaning of ^ and $
x modifier     # switch on the free spacing mode (or comment mode, or verbose mode)
```

You can easily change this pattern to add other fields.

Note: if the mail or the name may be empty sometimes, you can change `[^\r\n]+` to `[^\r\n]*`.

Instead of building a csv you can use the foreach loop to insert the values in your database. I suggest to start a transaction before the loop:

```
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $mbox, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    try {  
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $usr, $pwd);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);      
        $dbh->beginTransaction();
        $query = 'INSERT INTO myTable (name, mail) VALUES (?, ?)';
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);

        foreach($m as $item) {
            $sth->execute(array($item['name'], $item['mail']));
        }

        $dbh->commit();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $dbh->rollback();
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $dbh = null;
}
```

Comment: That is great thank you. I changed it to the following so it would go to the csv and now get two lots of emails and two lots of names on each row but the data I need is all on one row! Thank you very much!

Comment: $fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
   if (preg_match_all($patt, $string, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
       foreach($m as $item) {
           echo $item['name'] . ',' . $item['mail'] . PHP_EOL;
           fputcsv($fp, $item);
       }
}

Comment: @AndrewCowley: note that if your final goal is to put all in a database, the csv step is not needed.

Comment: Thanks Casmir. I guess I would just INSERT INTO (name,email) VALUES ($item['name'],$item['email'])?